# captions overlap figures in *.pdf file after dvi2pdf (while appearing normal in *.dvi file)

Tags: floats

For some reason, figure captions that appear underneath the figure in the *.dvi file, overlap the figure in the *.pdf file generated using div2pdf.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks,

Ofer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Even weirder, that some figures are displayed correctly, some others are not and I don't think there is any difference in the code/eps files.

Comment: I have the same problem and I really need to generate .pdf from .dvi directly. Any help please ?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. The problem was solved as follows: After generating the dvi file, I changed the format to ps (simply click on dvi/ps in WinEdt) and finally generate the pdf file using the ps file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Masroor It does attempt to answer the question.  It suggests using the classical DVI->PS->PDF instead of just DVI->PDF.